# Are there any ways to limit the resource usage of Calibre?

Tags: windows-7, calibre

I'm trying to upload a collection of books to my Kindle using Calibre and its resource usage is through the roof:

[image]

While its usage of all my cores is impressive, this may be a bit extreme. **Is there any way to limit the amount of RAM/CPU that Calibre can use?**

Turning off several other programs (and no longer adding more books to the conversion queue) the memory usage drops slight. Still the three `calibre-parallel.exe *32` processes each use up a complete core. As for the memory usage, for all four processes combined its totals in **around 2 Gb**, which I honestly think is a little massive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BES (Battle Encoder Shirase)](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/) which is a small (lightweight) tool which limits the CPU usage for a specified process. I tried it on Windows 7 and it works.

Use this page to download: [Version 1.4.3 – June 22, 2011](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/#download)

Link: [How To Use](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/#usage)

> BES is a small tool which limits the CPU usage for a specified
>   process: for instance, you can limit the CPU usage of a process which
>   would use CPU 100%, down to 50% (or any percentage you like). With
>   this, you can use other programs comfortably while doing something
>   CPU-intensive in the background. By limiting the CPU load, you can
>   also cool down your CPU immediately when it happens to get too hot. Of
>   course the processing speed will slow down proportionally if you limit
>   the CPU usage, but it should be much better than crashing because of
>   heat or (in the worst scenario) having your computer broken with a
>   burned CPU.

The result with this solution:

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution @Mepher :-) Trying it right now

Comment: @Ivo: It [seems that](http://oldbugs.calibre-ebook.com/ticket/7817) other Calibre users are suffering from high CPU usage as well...

Comment: Definitely seems to reduce the load, doesn't help with the RAM off course but at least it keeps my computer usable.

Comment: The name is... crazy.

Answer (score 3):

In instead of throttling the amount of CPU cycles the program can use, it would make more sense to right-click the process in `Task Manager` and give it a `Below Normal` `Priority`.

That way the program will still be able to do what it needs to do when there is nothing else that needs to be done.  I often do this when I am I have a background task running, like 3D rendering, as it allows me to use the computer as normal.

With [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) you can also adjust its `Page Priority`, which I assume will change how the system allocates RAM to it.